# Opening GeoRiot Affiliate Link from Inside App?

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, affiliate

I've been using Linkshare links in my apps for a while now. It works fine.
I implemented the Apple's suggestion to absorb any redirects and call the last URL.

For those looking for it, [HERE IT IS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1629/_index.html).

I have a UIButton linked to a method that calls this:

```
[self openReferralURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
```

where link is a NSString with the following value (my Linkshare link)

> @"http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/stat?id=Jexmk6JU*OU&offerid=146261&type=3&subid=0&tmpid=1826&RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Fitunes.apple.com%252FWebObjects%252FMZStore.woa%252Fwa%252FviewSoftware%253Fid%253D353970672%2526partnerId%253D30"

This works fine. When I tap the button, it immediately launch App Store App without opening Safari first.

But when I change the link to the GeoRiot link below, it opens up Safari first, and then only open the App Store. I can't think of any reason why it is doing that.

> @"http://target.georiot.com/Proxy.ashx?grid=5700&id=Jexmk6JU*OU&offerid=146261&type=3&subid=0&tmpid=1826&RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Fitunes.apple.com%252FWebObjects%252FMZStore.woa%252Fwa%252FviewSoftware%253Fid%253D353970672%2526partnerId%253D30"

Anyone can help? Can you share your geotarget link for comparison with mine?
Anyway, I have 1 UIWebview that opens up a webpage with Geotarget links, and that
works fine (ie. directly opens the App Store App).

I'm out of idea right now. I think the problem may lie in the GeoRiot link, but I have
no idea why or what I should do since with the Linkshare link it works fine.

Comment: I hate it when this happens. After I post this question, I solved it.

Comment: Can you tell us how? I'm interested...

Comment: Sure Andrea, see my answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been asking questions and answering them a lot these days, but for Andrea, here goes:

For those of you who are using georiot links, these methods/functions will work
well instead of the Apple Sample code.

```
// Process a URL to something iPhone can handle
- (void)openReferralURL:(NSURL *)referralURL
{
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:referralURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    [conn release];
}

// Save the most recent URL in case multiple redirects occur
// "iTunesURL" is an NSURL property in your class declaration
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{


    if (response) {
        NSMutableURLRequest *r = [[request mutableCopy] autorelease]; // original request
        [r setURL: [request URL]];


        self.iTunesURL = [r URL];

        if ([self.iTunesURL.host hasSuffix:@"itunes.apple.com"]) {

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:self.iTunesURL];

        }


        return r;
    } else {
        return request;
    }

}
```

And to use, just call:

```
[self openReferralURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://target.georiot.com/Proxy.ashx?grid=5700&id=Jexmk6JU*OU&offerid=146261&type=3&subid=0&tmpid=1826&RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Fitunes.apple.com%252Fus%252Fapp%252Fiquiksplash-pro-all-in-one%252Fid378458261%253FpartnerId%253D30"]];
```

Probably you should also use a URL shortener tool to clean up the long URL mess, but either way it works ok.

Comment: Thanks! Also the original code in the Apple Q&A works fine for me. Just made a small change to make it ARC compatible...

Answer (score 0):

You found itunes url it's ok.

You have http://itunes.apple.com address, what about the ssl redirection issue ? 
because itunes portal will redirect you https://itunes.apple.com address. 
I also improved your `if` branch of iTunes check part.

```
 // Process a URL to something iPhone can handle
 - (void)openReferralURL:(NSURL *)referralURL
 {
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:referralURL
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:30.0];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    [conn release];
 }

 // Save the most recent URL in case multiple redirects occur
 // "iTunesURL" is an NSURL property in your class declaration
 - (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
    if (response) {
        NSMutableURLRequest *r = [[request mutableCopy] autorelease]; // original request
        [r setURL: [request URL]];

        NSURL *iTunesUrl = [r URL];
        NSLog(@"Processing affiliate link : %@", iTunesUrl);
        if ([[iTunesUrl absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"https"] && [iTunesUrl.host hasSuffix:@"itunes.apple.com"]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:iTunesUrl];
        }        
        return r;
    } else {
        return request;
    }
 }
```